# Is it possible to get data from an html form?

Tags: forms, symfony, controller

So, I have a form inside my "show" view so that the user can change some data before submitting it.
I've been asked to manually add a field with the `render` method
The result looks like a multi select from which we can select the result of a sql request that displays schools according to a filter.

Before I had to do that, I had a many-to-many that would show me every schools without any filter. I thought (and still think) this would be neat to use this form part to save my html datas

So I created an HTML form that would display what I need, and give it the required attributes to get saved somewhere (id, names, label for, etc), so that the HTML form kind of have the same attributes my previous form has.

My main problem is that I can't get anything in the dumps I do after submitting the form, and I don't know why.

Here's my form in its HTML version:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="public_ecolesDispo" class="col-md-4 control-label">Ecoles à lier</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {% if liste2 is defined %}
                <select id="public_ecolesDispo" name="public[ecolesDispo][]" multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker">
                    {% for l in liste2 %}
                        <option value="{{ l }}">{{ l }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

My question is, is there a way to get the posted data via $form->getData() and to set it manually inside my controller?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller you can use the request to get POST data like this :

```
public function yourFunctionThatReceivePostDataAction(Request $request) 
{
   dump($request->request->get('public')['ecolesDispo']);
   exit;
}
```